# How to save Integer to Database(SQLite)

Tags: android, database, performance, sqlite, android-sqlite

In my program, I have a database and there is a table in my database in the name of the student , In the student table, there is a column named StudentID that should save ten numbers now my problem is The Student ID column can not save the numbers,When I enter numbers less than ten it shows the save message but in logcat have error and when I enter the ten numbers, it will be out from the program.

Sorry for my poor English language.

SQLite Code For Student Table :

```
create table student(student_id integer(10) primary key not null , class_id int , student_name nvarchar(50) , FOREIGN KEY (class_id) REFERENCES class(class_id))
```

Save Student Method :

```
    public void SaveStudent(int studentId , int classID , String studentName)
{
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put("student_id" , studentId);
    values.put("class_id" , classID);
    values.put("student_name" , studentName);

    database.insert("student" , null , values);

    Toast.makeText(context, "Save!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Get Student Information :

```
    Button saveStudent_btn = (Button)viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.item_btn_SaveStudent);

    saveStudent_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    HashMap<String, Object> obj = (HashMap<String, Object>)     adapter.getItem(position);
    int classId = (int) obj.get("class_id");

    EditText studentName_et = (EditText)viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.item_et_StudentName);
    String studentName = studentName_et.getText().toString();

    EditText studentId_et = (EditText)viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.item_et_StudentId);
    int studentId = Integer.parseInt(studentId_et.getText().toString());

    database.OpenDatabase();
    database.SaveStudent(studentId , classId , studentName);
    database.close();

    }
    });
```

Logcat error for when entered 10 numbers:

```
02-23 19:05:07.850 1896-1896/com.example.user.classmanager E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.user.classmanager, PID: 1896
        java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "4318659489"
        at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
        at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:413)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:367)
 com.example.user.classmanager.SecondTab$1$1$1.onClick(SecondTab.java:94)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5225)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21195)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
```

logcat error for less then 10 numbers :

```
  02-23 19:42:32.502 10388-10388/com.example.user.classmanager E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting 

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: student.student_id (code 1555)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:780)
at com.example.user.classmanager.DatabaseHandler.SaveStudent(DatabaseHandler.java:189)
at com.example.user.classmanager.SecondTab$1$1$1.onClick(SecondTab.java:97)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the length of `int`, your number overflow.
Use `Long` instead .

```
Long  studentId = Long.parseLong(studentId_et.getText().toString());
```

`int` range in java from -2,147,483,648 To 2,147,483,647 . and your number overflows it .

And for `UNIQUE constraint failed` you violates the primary key constraints. Make sure the id generated is unique and not null always.

Comment: this type (integer 10) is good type for database ? I do not want the size of the program to increase

Comment: Well it all depends on your data structure if you are only using data as local means if there is no syncing to server then you can use studentId as auto Increment . Othewise just keep it that way . size has nothing to do with it untill its inside range.

Comment: hey friend i have new problem , after save Number , when show the numbers ,The stored numbers are storedَ As other numbers @ADM

Comment: This seems some logical issue in your code . You should ask a new question for this issue .First Debug your code check what exactly is saving to database .

Comment: you can see my new quetion : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49304779/diffrent-result-after-save-number-as-long-in-database

Answer (score 1):

`UNIQUE constraint failed` this mean you are trying to insert id value which is already exists and that violates the primary key's uniqueness..to a void that make the `StudentID` auto increment.

Comment: oh , Thank you for your help

Comment: @NimaKhalili you are wellcome